# How to add new keys to the object with matching condition without mutating the state?

Tags: reactjs, loops, object, react-hooks, switch-statement

I have array of of objects that looks like this

```
foodNutrients: Array(85)
{nutrientId: 1008, nutrientName: "Energy", unitName: "KCAL" value: 400,}
...
```

I want to map over all of the objects and for every object it checks `nutrientName` if it matches specific keyword I want to rename the key with corresponding keyword from my excel sheet and save its value.

In this instance the result would be `Energy_100g: 400`.

Then I want to loop over remaining 85 objects and add all of them to the state below.

```
const [convertedIngredients, setConvertedIngredients] = useState({
    product_name: "",
    nutriments: {},
    serving_size: "",
    serving_quantity: "",
  });
```

```
selectedItem.foodNutrients.map((foodNutrient) => {
      switch (foodNutrient.nutrientName) {
        case "Energy":
          setConvertedIngredients((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            nutriments: {
              Energy_100g: foodNutrient.value,
            },
          }));
          break;
plus another 100+ cases
```

I want my state `nutriments` object to be populated with 85 new keys, but I only get 1 because, each loop overwrites it.

Comment: Invert your logic a little bit. Instead of setting state on each object that needs an update, create a new array and update the state with the new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help solving your issue.

```
selectedItem.foodNutrients.map((foodNutrient) => {
      switch (foodNutrient.nutrientName) {
        case "Energy":
          setConvertedIngredients((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            nutriments: {
              ...prev.nutriments,
              Energy_100g: foodNutrient.value,
            },
          }));
          break;
```

But even in this case you must remember that every key in the object must be unique and if you try to insert a duplicate it would write the existing one. or if you are expecting multiple values under the same key you can also do something like this.

```
selectedItem.foodNutrients.map((foodNutrient) => {
      switch (foodNutrient.nutrientName) {
        case "Energy":
          setConvertedIngredients((prev) => prev.nutriments.hasOwnProperty('Energy_100g') ? {
            ...prev,
            nutriments: {
              ...prev.nutriments,
              Energy_100g: [...prev.nutriments.Energy_100g, foodNutrient.value],
            },
          } : {
                ...prev,
                nutriments: {
                  ...prev.nutriments,
                  Energy_100g: [foodNutrient.value],
                },
              });
          break;
```

pardon and ignore any typo above which lead to a syntactical error.
Cheers,